# Visual Studio 2010 setup project, missing icon in Uninstall or change a program list

Tags: c#, wpf

I've made a setup project for my wpf application and set an icon for the Start menu and the shortcut on the desktop.

How do I get it to add my icon to the Uninstall or change a program list ? Now it just displays the annoying default icon.

Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Click your Setup project root node in solution explorer and see the properties window. You'll see the required setting there.
[image]

Comment: For those whose project are not in C#, note that this is independent of C#. This worked for my C++ projects. I think it will work for any setup project.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this property window NOT with right click and Properties, but instead you have to select the installer project and hit F4.